# Exception details are not getting logged in the Error log

Tags: .net, exception, enterprise-library

Its a WPF - PRISM -WPF application with Enterprise library Exception handling, logging and tracing blocks. In our application we handle the exception and log appropriate information in the error log using EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.

The Weird thing with my issue is, Error log is properly getting created with the exception details through a Unit test method i have created. But when the application is debugged or run by executing the exe and if it encounters an Exception the Error log is created as a 0KB file. the exception details are not getting written.

Am not sure what i am missing, presently i dont have the EL source code in the secure environment to debug and see whats going wrong! Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Issues like this are typically permissions problems. Devs often run as admin, so when needing to create things like event log sources or files in the .exe directory it works, but fails when run as a more limited user.

What trace listener are you using? Does your user in production have permissions to set up the destination for the logging?

Comment: Hey Chris thanks for answering! n i found the real issue. It was because the extended property values sent for logging where null and internally the Enterprise library was failing when it tried to format the null values! I think they missed few null checks! I had to modify my logic to add extended properties only while they are not null and it worked perfect! Thanks!